# How to redraw canvas with a new image via ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height) script action?

Tags: html5-canvas, html5-video, video-capture

I am trying to refresh canvas image coming as video frame usbcam input every 5 sec
Since redraw fails I was told to clear image/canvas first
Nice example on how to
HTML5 Clear Canvas Tutorial
file:///D:/firefox%20pobrane/HTML5%20Canvas%20Clear%20Canvas%20Tutorial.htm
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
should work as suggested
but I don't get canvas cleared if I insert
 context.stroke();
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
directly
Canvas clear works for me as button click event only
Any idea how to modify the above example to have canvas cleared by script code only (timeOut  .. 5000) ?
Another example
file:///D:/firefox%20pobrane/javascript%20-%20How%20to%20clear%20the%20canvas%20for%20redrawing%20-%20Stack%20Overflow.htm

Comment: I am sorry demo link is the following  http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-clear-canvas/

Comment: context.stroke();
 
      
       setTimeout(function(){ context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width,            canvas.height);}, 5000);  Ok, the above line clears context with graphics run locally or remotely (remote html code is editable on-line). Have to try with image populated canvas

Comment: Ok, I can clear canvas with                                                                                              function photo(){context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
     }
     
     
      setTimeout(function(){ photo();}, 10000);
      
      setTimeout(function(){ context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);}, 20000);
      
       setTimeout(function(){ photo();}, 10000);  but don't get image refreshed with the last context.drawImage line (function)